# flask-restful with flask-auth :multiple HTTP method with different authentication

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, flask, flask-restful, flask-httpauth

i'm trying to have same url that have multiple HTTP (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) method and for each method it has different authentication using flask-auth.

i tried creating more than class like

```
class GetUser(Resource):


    decorators = [Users.auth.login_required]
    def get(self):
        '''..etc'''

class PostUser(Resource):


    decorators = [Admin.auth.login_required]
    def post(self):
        '''..etc'''

restful_api.add_resource(GetUser,'/User')
restful_api.add_resource(PostUser,'/User')
```

but what happend is that `restful_api.add_resource(PostUser,'/User')` will override `restful_api.add_resource(GetUser,'/User')`

Comment: Something wrong with ```@Admin.auth.login_required
def post(...)```

Comment: @svrist what's wrong with it ?

Comment: @svrist: that won't work with *class based views* such as those used by Flask-RESTful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reasonable option I can see is that you create a subclass of Flask-RESTful's `Resource` class and implement per-method decorators yourself. Then your resources can inherit from your class to have this functionality.

In your `Resource` subclass, you will need to provide an alternative implementation of the `dispatch_request` method: [https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/**init**.py#L543](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L543).

The code that handles decorators is this:

```
    for decorator in self.method_decorators:
        meth = decorator(meth)
```

I guess you can change the `method_decorators` to a dictionary, and then apply the decorators as follows:

```
    for decorator in self.method_decorators[request.method.lower()]:
        meth = decorator(meth)
```

Then your example above becomes:

```
class User(MyResource):
    method_decorators = {
        'get': [Users.auth.login_required],
        'post': [Admin.auth.login_required]
    }

    def get(self):
        '''..etc'''

    def post(self):
        '''..etc'''

restful_api.add_resource(User,'/User')
```

Answer (score 3):

i found out i could do this also

```
class User(Resource):


    @Admin.auth.login_required
    def post(self):
        '''..etc'''
    @Users.auth.login_required
    def get(self):
        '''..etc'''
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the decorator receives the extra `self` argument, since you are decorating a method instead of a function. For some decorators this may not be an issue, but some may not expect that extra argument.